# Does the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ have non-discrete "continuity-preserving" refinements?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

For topologies $\tau,\sigma$ on the same set $X$, say that $\tau$ **stably refines** $\sigma$ iff $\tau\supseteq\sigma$ (so $\tau$ is finer than $\sigma$ in the usual sense) and moreover every $\sigma$-continuous function $X\rightarrow X$ is also $\tau$-continuous. Stable refinement is a much stricter notion than refinement; for example, the only proper stable refinement of the indiscrete topology on a set is the discrete topology on that same set. My question is:

> Does the usual topology $\eta$ on $\mathbb{R}$ have any proper non-discrete stable refinements?

It's easy to see that if $\tau$ is a stable refinement of $\eta$ and $[0,1]\in\tau$, then $\tau$ is discrete: for any real $a$ consider the function $f_a(x)=-(x-a)^2$. Since $f_a$ is continuous in the usual sense it must be continuous in $\tau$, but that means $f_a^{-1}([0,1])=\{a\}$ must be $\tau$-open, so all singletons are $\tau$-open. The same basic idea works for any closed-not-open set in place of $[0,1]$, but it doesn't work with something more complicated like $\mathbb{Q}$, <s>and in fact I suspect that there is a non-discrete stable refinement of $\eta$ with respect to which $\mathbb{Q}$ is open. But I don't see how to prove this.</s> (EDIT: this guess was wrong, see Robert Israel's argument below.)

Comment: I think you mean "Does the usual topology $\eta$ on $\mathbb R$ have any proper non-discrete stable refinements?".  Obviously $\eta$ is a stable refinement of itself.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Quite right, fixed!

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Didn't mean to, fixed!

Comment: Your argument leads to the fact that for any open set $A$ of $\tau$, any $\eta$-open interval in $A^c$ has its $\eta$-closure in $A^c$. In fact, if not the case, there is a point $x$ in $A$ with (say) a right $\eta$- neighbourhood $(x,x+\epsilon)$ entirely contained in $A^c$, which leads to the conclusion that $\tau$ is discrete thanks to a similar argument to what you wrote for $[0,1]$. Then, since $\tau$ has the above property (and is scaling and translation invariant), I suspect that one can conclude that either $\tau=\eta$, or $\tau=2^{\mathbb R}$. Do you have any ideas from here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant simply “one can conclude that $\tau=\eta$.”

Answer (score 4):

If every $\eta$-continuous function is $\tau$-continuous, then every $\eta$-homeomorphism is also a $\tau$-homeomorphism.

Suppose $\mathbb Q$ is $\tau$-open.  Then  $\sqrt{2} \mathbb Q$ is also $\tau$-open, since $z \to \sqrt{2}z$ is a homeomorphism.  And then $\{0\} = \mathbb Q \cap (\sqrt{2} \mathbb Q)$ is $\tau$-open.  By translation, every singleton is $\tau$-open.

Comment: This is nice, but I think it should be a comment, not an answer. (The actual question is whether $\eta$ has any stable refinements, not whether specifically adding $\mathbb{Q}$ does the job. And since we can whip up by transfinite recursion a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that for every image $Y$ of $X$ under an $\eta$-autohomeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ we have $X\cap Y$ has size continuum, I don't think this argument can be generalized to answer the question.)

Comment: Maybe a better candidate for being $\tau$-open would be $\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$.  In fact, consider the topology $\tau$ consisting of sets $U \backslash K$ where $U$ is $\eta$-open and $K$ is $\eta$-meagre.  This would be a non-discrete stable refinement if the requirement for stability was that $\eta$-homeomorphisms are $\tau$-homeomorphisms.  Are there $\eta$-continuous functions that are not $\tau$-continuous?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you know the answer to your last question? It looks very interesting

Comment: I do not know the answer.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau$ be some topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d\in\mathbb{N}^+$) finer than the usual topology (symbol omitted) such that $\tau$ is closed under continuous preimages. We claim that $\tau$ is discrete.

Let $U\in\tau$ be a $\tau$-open non-open set. Since $\mathbb{R}^d\smallsetminus U$ is not closed, there is a convergent sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d\smallsetminus U$ for all $n$ but $x\in U$.

Fix a sequence of decreasing positive reals $0<\ldots<b_2<a_1<b_1<a_0<b_0$ such that $\lim_n a_n=\lim_n b_n=0$. We want to find continuous functions $f,g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^d$ such that:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
f\upharpoonright[a_0,b_0]&\equiv x_0\qquad & g\upharpoonright[b_0,\infty)&\equiv x_0\\
f\upharpoonright[a_1,b_1]&\equiv x_1\qquad & g\upharpoonright[b_1,a_0]&\equiv x_1\\
f\upharpoonright[a_2,b_2]&\equiv x_2\qquad & g\upharpoonright[b_2,a_1]&\equiv x_2\\
&\vdots & &\vdots\\
f(0)&=x & g(0)&=x
\end{alignat*}
To show such $f,g$ exist, note that so far we partially defined $f,g$ as continous functions over closed domains, so that Tietze extension implies there are continuous extensions $f,g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^d$ with full domain.

> *Claim.* $f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(U)=\{0\}$.
>
> *Proof.* For all $y>0$, either there is some $n$ such that $y\in[a_n,b_n]$ and $f(y)=x_n\notin U$, or there exists some $n$ such that $y\in[b_n,a_{n-1}]$ (let $[b_0,a_{-1}]:=[b_0,\infty)$) and $g(y)=x_n\notin U$. In either case $y\notin f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(U)$. On the other hand, $0\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(U)$ since $f(0)=g(0)=x\in U$.

Let $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be arbitrary, and define $F,G:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ via $F(y)=f(|y-\theta|)$ and $G(y)=g(|y-\theta|)$. Then since $F,G$ are continuous, one has:
\begin{align*}
\{\theta\}&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:|y-\theta|=0\}\\
&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:|y-\theta|\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(U)\}\\
&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:f(|y-\theta|)\in U\land g(|y-\theta|)\in U\}\\
&=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:F(y)\in U\land G(y)\in U\}\\
&=\underbrace{F^{-1}(U)}_{\in\tau}\cap \underbrace{G^{-1}(U)}_{\in\tau}\\
&\in \tau
\end{align*}
Since $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is arbitrary, $\tau$ is discrete.

It follows that if $\tau$ is any topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$ closed under continuous preimages, then $\tau$ is either trivial, Euclidean, or discrete.